# Placing figures side by side

Tags: subfloats

How to place figures side by side with two different captions and one common caption, while in the list of figures only common caption will show?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Please have a look to the "Related" questions on the right side.  For me it seems your question and the answer you can find there ... If not please give more informations, for example show us with a MWE, what you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 3):

You could load the `subcaption` package and use two `subfigure` environments inside a `figure` environment. Each `subfigure` can be given its own `\caption`.

In the example below, I've given equal sizes (of `0.48\textwidth`) to the subfigures; obviously, unequal sizes are also possible. The horizontal line below the figure is drawn purely to illustrate with width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit "demo" for your real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{file1}
    \caption{Caption of first subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hspace{\fill}  % for some horizotal separation 
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{file2}
    \caption{Caption of second subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A float with two subfigures}
\end{figure}
\hrule  % just to illustrate width of text block
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mico, the response is very helpful. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: @sudipkd - You're most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are looking for something like this:

[image: captions]

Use the package `subcaption`, which is in the basic installation of LaTeX.

The minimal example of the document is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{noimage}
    \subcaption{First subcaption here.}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{noimage}
    \subcaption{Second subcaption here.}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{One common caption for both figures.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But still, you should include your own example of what you are looking for.

Comment: A small comments: This will create an overfull hbox, as you have two minipages of `.5\textwidth` separated by an interword space. The `%` after the first minipage is missing.

Comment: Thanks @Vaclav Pavlik, for helping. Sorry for late response.